# Nginx - Redirect ignoring server_name

Tags: nginx, redirect

```
#default:
server { 
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 404;
}

server { 
    listen 443 default_server;

    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/dummy.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/dummy.key;

    return 404;
}


#old-domain:
server { 
    listen 80;

    server_name old-domain.com;
    server_name www.old-domain.com;

    return 301 https://www.old-domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    server_name old-domain.com;
    server_name www.old-domain.com;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/old-domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/old-domain.key;

    #catch all
    return 301 https://new-domain.com;
}


#new-domain:
server { 
    listen 80;

    server_name new-domain.com;
    server_name www.new-domain.com;

    return 301 https://www.new-domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;

    server_name new-domain.com;
    server_name www.new-domain.com;

    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/new-domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/new-domain.key;

    ....
}
```

As, requested, here is the output of curl -I for the various requests:

**curl -I http://old.domain.com**

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
>   Server: nginx/1.16.1
>   Date: Mon, 11 Nov 2019 07:48:57 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html
>   Content-Length: 169
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Location: https://www.old.domain.com/

**curl -I https://old.domain.com**

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
>   More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>   curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
>   establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
>   how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Comment: I have added a more detailed example of my config.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Please post an example curl request on what's happening and what's expected to happen.

Comment: I have added the curl output to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem it's with the certificates. You need to add the ssl proper certificate to the server block that you are redirecting on the old domain. Make sure that the certificate on the old domain is correct or it won't work